# Vector to DefaulTableModel

Tags: java, jtable, deserialization

I have a serilize file which cntains the DataVector of a Jtable. when i wanna deserialize it throws a error telling me that Vector cann't be cast into a default tableModel.

Here the serialize method:

```
fileOut.writeObject(model2.getDataVector()); //I save just the Data Vector.
```

Here the deserialization process:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Harry/Desktop/clients.txt"));
      DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)in.readObject();
      JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
```

How to cast from vector to default table model to can deserialize the data vector back into my Jtable?

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking you have three choices:

1. Serialize the entire `DefaultTableModel`.  This is ok for short-lived applications but you should not rely on it as a consistent mechanism for storing data long term.
2. Serialize the data Vector along with the column count and column names.  Deserialize this data on the reader side and construct a new `DefaultTableModel` using the `DefaultTableModel(Vector, Vector)` constructor.  Note that if you are already aware of the column names during deserialization you won't need to pass this data over the wire.
3. Implement your own `TableModel`, which wraps an underlying `List<T>` of your Serializable data items.  This would be my preferred choice.

Comment: I serialized the dataVector, and to get it back from the 3 choices you got me the 2nd one is appropiate, but how can i get it back into defaultTableModel from vector?

Comment: You need to construct a new DefaultTableModel, passing in the Vector.

Comment: DefaultTableModel(Vector v) dtm = new DefaultTableModel(Vector v);  ?